# Why does the following function gets stuck when I hit it from postman?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I am trying to update a record in MongoDB in the following function but sometimes it gets stuck when I hit the endpoint from the postman and I don't know why does it happen? Help me identify the problem here

```
update: (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let image = req.file.path;
    let newPost = {
        title: req.body.title,
        slug: req.body.slug,
        body: req.body.body,
        image: image
    };
    Post.findOne({_id: id}, (err, post) => {
        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(403).json({
                errors: err.errors
            });
        }
        else
        {
            if(!post)
            {
                res.status(404).json({
                    message: "Post not found"
                });                   
            }
            else
            {
                let oldImage = post.image;                
                Post.updateOne({_id: id}, newPost, (err, post) => {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        return res.status(403).json({
                            errors: err.errors
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(oldImage)

                            fs.unlinkSync(oldImage);
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            post
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your code looks fine (I have only read it, not tested it!). But there might be problems when e.g. an exception is thrown synchronously. This could happen, for example, in the call to `fs.unlinkSync` (please note that I'm not saying there the problem is in this line, this is just an example).

If this happens, then further execution of this route is stopped, and you will never receive a result. The same could happen at other places as well, so maybe a `try`/`catch` around everything which results in sending a `500` would be a good idea.